# Python subprocess.CalledProcessError:returned non-zero exit status 12/127

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am trying to deploy an existing AMI onto AWS.
I tried to launch the amitest cluster using Cygwin on Windows and tried with Ubuntu as well.
In both cases, i am running into this issue:

```
[user1@user1...lab1/amitest]$ ./spark-ec2 -i useruseastkey.pem -k useruseastkey --copy launch amitest
Setting up security groups...
Creating security group amitest-master
Creating security group amitest-slaves
Creating security group amitest-zoo
Checking for running cluster...
Using Spark AMI: ami-99bb0ff0
Launching instances...
Launched slaves, regid = r-67e38ac7
Launched master, regid = r-5ee089fe
Waiting for instances to start up...
Waiting 120 more seconds...
Deploying files to master...
/bin/sh: rsync: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./spark_ec2.py", line 759, in <module>
    main()
  File "./spark_ec2.py", line 648, in main
    setup_cluster(conn, master_nodes, slave_nodes, zoo_nodes, opts, True)
  File "./spark_ec2.py", line 363, in setup_cluster
    deploy_files(conn, "deploy.generic", opts, master_nodes, slave_nodes, zoo_nodes)
  File "./spark_ec2.py", line 604, in deploy_files
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'rsync -rv -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i useruseastkey.pem' '/tmp/tmpbB27rZ/' 'root@ec2-......compute-1.amazonaws.com:/'' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

I am able to login to the instance, I also see that all the 4 instances are up and running.

Would like some direction here. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like `rsync` isn't installed, perhaps you should just install it?

Comment: Hi Eric, I have the latest version of `Rsync` already installed.

Comment: Then try putting the full path to it in your command, because it is apparently not finding it in its `PATH`

Comment: Thanks Eric, that resolved my issue.